# use of deleted function CONSTRUCTOR, no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

This code gives me the following errors at the line `My_grammar g;` :

```
no matching function for call to boost::spirit::qi::grammar<My_grammar>::grammar()’

use of deleted function ‘My_grammar::My_grammar()’
```

I don't get it, isn't there supposed to be a default (not deleted) constructor ? But the problem is probably elsewhere.

I'd implement a constructor, but it brings new errors, and the tutorials/examples never use the same approach (some with constructors, some without), or use classes neither I, the doc, the compiler or google know anything about ([CParser ??](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8516/An-Introduction-to-the-Boost-Spirit-Parser-framewo)). I think it might be because of the headers I (don't) include, since there is A LOT I can choose from under boost/spirit. Again, people in possibly out-of-date tutorials don't seem to include the same, or to use ones that don't exist with my yesterday, apt-get fetched, most probably up-to-date version of boost. I'm using Eclipse, in case it changes anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_rule.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit;


#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG

struct My_grammar :
    public boost::spirit::qi::grammar<My_grammar>
{
public:
    template <typename ScannerT>
    struct definition
    {
    public:
        definition(My_grammar const& self)
        {
            sentence
                = 'a';
        }
        boost::spirit::qi::rule<ScannerT> sentence;
        boost::spirit::qi::rule<ScannerT> const&    start() const { return sentence; }
    };
};



int main() {
    My_grammar g;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I feel a lot more questions coming next (e.g : I already tried and failed the parse() function), but I want to solve it one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are stuck with a "classical" spirit parser skeleton.

Spirit V2 is rather different, and has looooong superseded V1:

- Migration Documentation: [Porting from Spirit 1.8.x](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/notes/porting_from_spirit_1_8_x.html)

Here's how you'd write the grammar definition in Spirit V2:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It>
struct My_grammar : public qi::grammar<It> {
    My_grammar() : My_grammar::base_type(sentence) {
        sentence = 'a';
    }
    qi::rule<It> sentence;
};

int main() {
    My_grammar<std::string::const_iterator> g;
}
```

Comment: This indeed compiles. Being nitpicky, shouldn't you use your namespace when declaring sentence ?

Comment: Ah I see it now. It's the same thing after all